# PHP how to make an uploaded file link is internal ip when internally and public ip when in public with this snippet i got?

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-match, portal

I am doing a php portal.

i did an announcement section where user can post message and attach a file.

so in this situation, a user has uploaded one and at the page, there will be a hyperlink for the attachment. if i hover on it, i can see this "192.168.0.100/Announcement/file.pdf"

so logically if im in the internal network and click on that it would not be a problem as it can get the file from that ip.

next situation is i have forwarded the server ip so that public can access from outside. now i'm as a user accessing from outside.

so if i were to go to the announcement location and hover on it again it will show the same link "192.168.0.100/Announcement/file.pdf". I will definitely wont be able to open it as that ip is internal.

so i am thinking how can i make it when i'm internal, the ip is the internal one and when im outside,the ip link would be the public?

i got this snippet from a ex colleague but i dont really know what the code does. Can someone help me explain this? i tried searching this thing i want to do on the net,but i dont have a proper keyword for it.

below is the snippet:

```
<?php
//filename constant.php

define('SERVERIP',((preg_match("/^192\.168/i",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))?'192.168.0.100':'175.136.xxx.xxx'),true);
?>
```

And below is part of the code in the page for the announcement and attachment:

```
include('_include/constant.php');
$dir = "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/Announcement/";
$http = sprintf('http://%s/Announcement/',SERVERIP);

print '<td class="middle '.$CLASS.'" align="left" height="20">'.'<a href="http://'.SERVERIP.'/Announcement/'.$filename.'" target="_blank">'.$filename .'</a></td>';
```

Can any php pros here help me to understand whats happening so that next time i know what i'am actually implementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a ternary operation, the results of which are being assigned to the constant `SERVERIP`. It is using a regex to match against the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, if it begins with `192.168`, then it gets the `192.168` value, otherwise it gets the `175.136` value. And for some reason it is passing `true` to enforce a case insensitive search.

You can read more on define within the [PHP docs](http://us.php.net/define).

Lighter example of ternary op:

```
$overlyComplex = true;

$thatDudesCodeSucks = (true === $overlyComplex) ? 'yes' : 'no';

// Shorthand for
if (true === $overlyComplex) {
    $thatDudesCodeSucks = 'yes';
} else {
    $thatDudesCodeSucks = 'no';
}

var_dump($thatDudesCodeSucks); // echos yes
```

Comment: Thnx @Mike Purcell !! i'll have a read on that php docs. I understand u explanation clearly and now i get the picture.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to implement any of this... you need to change how you are referencing the URLs and everything else will fall into place. For example, `<a href="/">this</a>` will show http://192.168.0.100/ when you are on the LAN in your company. When you access this website from the outside, it will show the IP address or domain name you are accessing from outside.

You should be using...

```
<a href="/something.pdf">something PDF</a>
```

as opposed to:

```
<a href="http://192.168.0.100/something.pdf>something PDF</a>
```

which is what it seems like you're doing.

Comment: I didnt think of this. i will try it out. Thnx @Ryan Kempt